# How to copy and paste the value or text from Google search box to ask.com's search box in the same windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, copy-paste

How to copy and paste the value or text from Google search box to ask.com's search box?

Please imagine a windows application with one webbrowser box on the left side and another webbrowser box on the right side, all embedded evenly in the same one windows application form.

I want to add a button that copies the value or text from Google search box and then converts these characters into a uppercase and then pastes it on the Ask.com's search box.

Google's searchbox ID is "lst-ib" and ask.com's search box ID is "q"

How do you programmatically copy and paste the value or text from Google search box to ask.com's search box?

Comment: This might not be what you're looking for, but if you go to `http://google.com/search?q=<urlencoded search terms>` it will bring up the results.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the search term from the URL (in `DocumentCompleted` event) and just construct a proper ask.com search URL.

Or you can (again in `DocumentCompleted`, or in your button click handler) use standard DOM methods to get the value:

```
HtmlElement searchBox = GoogleBrowser.Document.getElementById("lst-ib");
```

Comment: I was trying to find a code that would copy the value from the google search box and paste it on ask.com's search box.   I need help in setting the value to the search field of google'searh box  askbrowser.Document.GetElementById("q").SetAttribute("value");